# Codeigniter - get penultimate row

Tags: codeigniter, row

How get the penultimate row at DB using active record?
I have the following statement:

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('sys_access', array('user' => $usid));
$ult_access = $query->last_row();
$this->data['ult_acsess'] = $ult_acsess->data;
```

This print in the view the last access at the system. But the last access is now (after login in the system), i need get the penultimate access.

Comment: so you want the last access before your login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question but if I do you want the last access before your login? If so just query the database ordered by whatever you're using to track, a time field, id etc then select the second record. IE:

```
$this->db->order_by('dateTime', DESC);//whatever field you're using to order this table by
$query = $this->db->get_where('sys_access', array('user' => $usid));
$data= $query->result_array();
$ult_access = $data[1];//your login will be $data[0]
```